# VB 2010 Express: Where do I change the default project location

Tags: vb.net

My files are all saved in C:\users\xxx. I want them in a different place by default. I've tried selecting the project name and bringing up the properties window but there is no place to change the default location. Anyway, if I save files to E:\VB, I'll get a set of folders like: E:\VB\test1\test1\bin\debug. Why not E:\VB\Test1 ????
How do I change the VB.NET default file location to E:\VB from C:\users\xxxx ???

RON

Comment: I opened up VB.NET, went to Options; changed all the default locations to E:\VB. Closed VB.NET; reoeneed. All the changes were thee but when I created a new project, and saved Module1, it wanted to save to: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Test11\Module1.vb. How do I get this to change by default to E:\VB\Projectname\Module1.vb?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about a large number of different features / settings.

- You can change the default save location in Tools, Options, Projects and Solution
- You probably want to uncheck the `Create folder for solution` checkbox when creating a project

Answer (score 0):

You created a new project. If you do `Save All`, it will prompt for a save location. Change that to match your preference and this new location will be used by VS from now on.